# Simulate bivariate bernoulli responses with predefined beta coefficients

Tags: multivariate-analysis, simulation, matlab, bernoulli-distribution, bivariate

I have a specific data matrix with features (mainly categorical). I want to simulate a multivariate bernoulli response, for example bivariate, but with a predefined vector of beta coefficients (most are nonzeros and some have zero values on purpose). Therefore, I will not have two different logistic models so to fit two different logistic regressions, but one bivariate and I want to examine if a predictor is jointly contributing to both models. Subsequently the aim is to apply a feature selection method and examine if the method will yield the correct (corresponding to nonzeros coefs) predictors.

I am new to multivariate distributions so I do not know how I can simulate bivariate bernoulli responses with a predefined vector of betas, for example in matlab. In addition, I suppose that I must take into account possible correlation between responses, which must be also done in the simulation code (maybe using a copula or something).

Comment: There's a paper linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32751268/1187671) that should help. The post itself deal with uniform variables, but the paper is more broad.